# Where do files sent from bluetooth go?

Tags: bluetooth

I am using HTC 8s, I recently received two 100 mb video files from my friend using Bluetooth.

Firstly I am not able to find the file, maybe the video format is not supported or for some other reason.

But in any case how do I remove this files ? I cannot see them anywhere in the videos section.

Please help me on this.

Comment: The video format is what?

Answer (score 4):

WP8 doesn't seem to grok videos properly, treating them as some kind of picture instead.

When I record one with my wp8 device it winds up under Photos/Albumns/Saved Pictures roll, and not videos.

And when I transfer a video via Bluetooth (using the steps below from gadgethelpline) the video also winds up under Photos/Albumns/Saved Pictures.

Once you've located them in Photos/Albumns/Saved Pictures, open up the single item, the click [...] for a delete option.

For anyone who doesn't know how to transfer files via bluetooth there is a great post at http://blog.gadgethelpline.com/bluetooth-file-transfer-windows-phone-8/ .

Comment: I am unable to locate the videos. :(

Comment: Not sure what to tell you.  I just repeated the process with an 8X and Nokia 810.  Videos wind up in same place.  Sorry sir...

Answer (score 0):

In my Microsoft Lumia 535, the stuff I share through Bluetooth(in case of receiving) are located accordingly to their type.

Suppose Audio *mp3* format will go to SD->Music folder,

Videos *mp4* to SD->Videos Folder and

Images *jpg* to Phone->Pictures->Saved Pictures.

You may want to connect your phone to a PC system to view everything you got. Sometimes unsupported files are kept hidden which is only accessible through PC. Either you want to copy and play there, delete it etc...

Comment: The SD/Phone difference, is that because you've selected SD/Phone as default locations for the file types?