# Where to find the video that I received over Bluetooth?

Tags: video, bluetooth

I am using [Nokia Lumia 520](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nokia_Lumia_520). I received a video file over Bluetooth from another Windows Phone. I don't know where to find the file. I checked the memory after I received it; it occupied system memory. Usually files I receive over Bluetooth resides in the saved pictures folder. But I couldn't find it this time. It was not there. How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Saved Pictures folder usually sorts pics and videos by date. Have you tried scrolling up and looking for the video between older saved pictures and videos?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/1376/106