# How to change location of file sent over bluetooth?

Tags: 8.1, bluetooth, nokia-lumia-720

I've got Lumia 720 Windows Phone 8.1. I'm not able to find the audio files sent over Bluetooth. Is there any way to find out where they are or maybe a way to change the location where the files are saved?

Comment: Which is the extension of the audio file that you are trying to find? It's a format that is natively recognized by the OS? Have you tried to find it using [files app](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/files/762e837f-461d-4847-8399-3526f54fc25e) or [Molipayer](http://www.windowsphone.com/pt-br/store/app/moliplayer-pro/19ea6d3e-e3d9-401d-b30a-f6471811fe08) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/1376/106