# How do i locate PDF files sent over bluetooth but not opened with Acrobat yet?

Tags: bluetooth, pdf

I received few PDF files via bluetooth but did not open them with my Acrobat after the receive was complete. Now when i tried to find them, i don't see them in my Acrobat list, nowhere else on my phone for that matter. How can i locate and use/delete those files? Also is there anyway to ensure that all PDF files get saved to SD card so that they at least stay visible for later use? Nokia Lumia 520 - Windows Phone v8!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/1376/106

Answer (score 1):

Go to settings then storage and choose where you want to save your downloads, apps.... You can use this [Microsoft Files app](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/files/9wzdncrfj3pl) for finding you documents.

Answer (score 0):

connect your phone to pc or the sd card then you can find them.. or else you can download any file manager app from the store and find the desired files and use or delete them.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8 doesn't have a native file explorer app like W10M. If you want to manage your stuff just like in W10M I suggest you to use [Metro file manager](https://www.microsoft.com/en-pk/store/p/metro-file-manager/9wzdncrfhzqz) app. While [Files](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/files/9wzdncrfj3pl) app is also another tool to overcome this gap in WP8.